# How do we Look up service-cluster-ip-range in Azure AKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I can look up Pods IPs range using the below command

```
kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -m 1 cluster-cidr
```

how do i lookup service-cluster-ip-range? I couldnt get using the below command

```
kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -m 1 cluster-cidr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Azure CLI to get it:

```
az aks show -n <cluster_name> -g <cluster_resource_group> [--subscription <subscription_id>] | grep serviceCidr
```